# Не пропадает надпись "Яндекс условия использования" с карты и не расходуется вызовы API Яндекс Карт

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, nextjs, яндекс-карта-api

Я использую API Яндекс карт в моем next js приложении с помощьюу библиотеки react-yandex-maps. Карта отображается корректно, я передаю в каждый запрос API-токен для JavaScript API (тариф бесплатный с ограничениями). Вот пример запроса:

```
https://core-renderer-tiles.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=23.04.30-1-b230426134730&x=4786&y=2390&z=13&scale=2&lang=ru_RU&apikey=[здесь мой api-ключ]&ads=enabled
```

Вот так в коде я передаю api-ключ:

```
<YMaps query={{ apikey: "[мой api-ключ]" }}>
```

Проблема в том, что в личном кабинете разработчика у меня не отображается, что я как-либо израсходовал API, а также с карты не пропадает надпись "Яндекс условия использования". Я хочу убедиться, что все делаю правильно, как я могу убрать надпись и корректно ли, что вызовы не расходуются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вы подключали карту, но [тарифицируемых запросов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html/#index__limits) на ней не было. В таком случае в кабинете разработчика на странице с подключенными API-интерфейсами будет написано, что израсходовано 0 запросов, но перейдя на страницу интерфейса в статистике ключа можно будет увидеть количество вызовов API с вашим ключом.

Что касается ссылки на условия использования на карте, то убирать копирайты Яндекса с карты запрещено [условиями использования сервиса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html/#index__conditions).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!